# Recursively adding to list returns null

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I want to take a list of smaller lists and add a copy of the first element of each small list to the end of each small list.  If that didn't make any sense, I'll give you an example:

f({(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), ...}) = {(0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), ...}

This is what I've got so far:

```
(define (add-end n set)
  (cond
    ((null? set) '())
    (cons (append (first set) (first (first set)))
          (add-end n (rest set)))))
```

This keeps giving me a null result, and I don't exactly know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails because you forgot the `else` part in the `cond` expression, also the way you're `appending` a single element to the end of a list is incorrect. This should fix the problems:

```
(define (add-end set)
  (cond ((null? set)
         '())
        (else
         (cons (append (first set) (list (first (first set))))
               (add-end (rest set))))))
```

But wait, there's a simpler solution if we use existing procedures:

```
(define (add-end set)
  (map (lambda (lst)
         (append lst (list (first lst))))
       set))
```

Explanation:

- We don't need an `n` parameter - for processing a list, we rarely have to know its length in advance
- Notice that we have to process each element of the input list to create a new output list, using `map` is the way to go in these cases
- Now it's a simple matter of `append`ing the first element of each list
- To build a proper list, remember that `append` requires that both of its arguments are lists, that explains the bit with the `(list (first lst))`

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(add-end '((0 0 1) (1 0 0) (0 1 0)))
=> '((0 0 1 0) (1 0 0 1) (0 1 0 0))
```

Comment: I see now.  What was giving me null before?

Comment: @CompNoob it was failing because you forgot the `else`. The`cons` part of the condition had no effect.